# Arduino Yun not working

Tags: arduino, project, arduino-yun

Sorry for my bad english,
 I 've been programming with an Arduino Yun for two weeks by now. It suddenly stopped working, with no noticeable reason at all.

- The rx light is the only one always ON (when I power the board)
- The other lights are always OFF
- My computer doesn't detect the board ( My USB ports don't work really well, but well enough to at least detect the board i think)
- The board doesn't succed in doing the sketch I previously uploaded (when the board worked)
- I've tryed doing the 3 resets, no changes at all
- I've asked in Arduino's forum, no answer 'till yet.
  What could be possibly happening? Please, I need help

Answer (score 1):

There are many, many things you can do to fry an Arduino, such as shorting outputs (driven high) directly to ground without a suitable resistor. It's likely you've done one of those things.

If that's the case, you'll probably just have to go and buy another one. You *may* get some help from some local electronics shop or a hobbyist if you can find one close but, if it's fried, there's not much you can do.

If it's a new device and you can convince the shop where you bought it that you haven't connected anything to it but the USB, you may be able to get a replacement for free, depending on your local consumer laws.

If there's even the slightest possibility that it may be your USB rather than the Arduino itself, you need to test that - get it hooked up to a different machine (preferably one with more reliable hardware) and see if you can recover.

Comment: Isn't there any way I can fix this? are you pretty sure it's fryed?

Comment: @MatiasFischer: no, not at all convinced, it's just a _likely_ explanation. Without having access to the device, I can't tell. You need local electronic knowledge if you want to know for sure. _Have_ you actually attempted to attach anything to it? If so, it's probably fried based on the info in your question. If not, it may be fried, or your machine itself may be acting up.

Comment: I attached the arduino to 2 Motors and a batterie, all inside a vehicle. The goal of the project was to command a vehicle via WiFi with a cellphone. I achieved that but then after some days of using it what I said happened.

Comment: @MatiasFischer, then I think you may have fried it. Check it in another machine, but be prepared for the worst. Post your circuit diagrams to the Stack Exchange Arduino site (http://arduino.stackexchange.com/) before trying again, there's some very smart people over there with a good understanding of electronics.

Comment: @paxdiablo Can you comment why you believe connecting an input pin to ground without a pull-up can damage the device.  Connecting an output pin to ground without a series resistor can damage the device by exceeding the current rating.

Comment: @MatiasFischer battery?  Beware that "Unlike other Arduino boards, if you are going to provide power to the board through this pin, you must provide a regulated 5V." from http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardYun

Comment: Jdr, apologies, I meant output driven high rather than input. Fixed the answer.